# margins/space appearing out of nowhere in mobile browsers.

Tags: html, css, browser, mobile

I'm working on [this page](http://grilatto.com.mx/www/) and i'm having a mobile issue.

While the page renders as you see on a computer browser. Loading it on an iphone or android phone creates a problem in the menu thw you would simulate by adding a margin left and top of each of the elements.

I can't figure out why this happens, I have checked that every element has a margin of zero in the css directly and it sill happens. What else should i try?

On a side note. Is there any reference or list of common CSS/JS/HTML considerations for mobile browser you would reccomend?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the link from before the doctype and put it in the `<head>` where it belongs.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Funky theme. It's properly positioned now. But i still have my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Before I begin working on any website, I usually reset the CSS.

Most browsers have their own unique default values for elements and they sometimes don't play well with your website.

You can, however, try and override all of these properties to effectively "reset" the CSS.

Yahoo provides a stylesheet you can include (I'd include it *before* all of your CSS):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But i am already using a reset file. So that's probably not the issue here. Let me still go ahead and apply it just to be sure.